# how to verify almost everywhere conditions in DCT

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, almost-everywhere

The Dominated convergence theorem says the following: Let $f_{i} \in L^{1}(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ such that

- $f_{i}$ converges pointwise $\mu$-a.e. and
- There exists $g \in L^{1}(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ such that for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$ $|f_{i}| \leq g$ $\mu$-a.e.

Then there exists a function $f \in L^{1}(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ so we have $f:= \lim_{i \to \infty}f_{i}$ a.e. and $\lim_{i \to \infty}\int_{X}|f_{i} -f|d\mu = 0$

But how do I specifically test for the almost-everywhere conditions? For example the following problem:

$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{n\sin(\frac{x}{n})}{x(x^{2}+1)}dx$

where $x \neq 0$

The $f_{n}$ converges pointwise to $\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}$ and we can also use that as a dominating function, i.e. $g(x)$. The overall result ends up being $\pi$.

BUT can I just assume pointwise convergence and a dominating function means the almost-everywhere condition is satisfied? I assume not, in which case I don't know how to specifically show that is satisifed.

Comment: If you have pointwise convergence, you have pointwise convergence everywhere, hence also pointwise convergence $\mu$-a.e.. In short, everywhere implies almost everywhere. But I think this is not your problem. Could you to try clarify your problem?

Comment: @Mark That makes sense now that you've typed it! I guess the $|f_{i}| \leq g \mu$-a.e. works if we have a dominating function, as the point where it might not dominate has measure zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, pointwise convergence implies convergence almost everywhere. Note that convergence almost everywhere just means that pointwise convergence is allowed to fail in a (measurable) set of measure zero. If this set of 'bad points' is empty, we don't have anything to worry about.

Btw, you may want to pay extra attention to $x=0$ in your example.

Comment: That makes sense! What about the a.e. dominance condition? If we find a dominant function then we know it is dominant a.e. because where it 'fails' has measure zero? Good catch on the $x=0$ in the example.

Comment: @learningmathematics Yes, the same logic applies for the dominant function. If it dominates in every point, then the set of 'bad points' is empty and there is no problem. The idea of measure theory is that things that happen on sets of measure 0 don't matter.